# Tabbar controller load empty xib

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I'm trying to build an app that have main view at the beginning with 3 buttons, then when the user press any button of these buttons, the tab bar view will appear with selected tab bar item.

My problem is here, when the tab bar view should appear ... it appears empty !!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    MainMenuViewController *mainMenuViewController = [[[MainMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainMenuViewController] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

//Button Action in main menu view
    -

```
 (IBAction)button1Action:(id)sender {
        TabbarViewController *tempView = [[TabbarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabbarViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tempView animated:YES];
        [tempView release];
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set viewControllers property of your TabbarViewController(of course if it is superclass of UITabBarController). Create your 3 viewControllers in init method of TabbarViewController, add them to array and set it as viewControllers property like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[[self class] superclass]);

        UIViewController *yourFirstViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        UIViewController *yourSecondViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        UIViewController *yourThirdViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

        yourFirstViewController.title = @"First";
        yourSecondViewController.title = @"Second";
        yourThirdViewController.title = @"Third";

        NSArray *threeViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:yourFirstViewController, yourSecondViewController, yourThirdViewController, nil];

        self.viewControllers = threeViewControllers;

        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```